# React Error, TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I encountered this error while using react-router-dom.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGl9W.png)

An error occurs when using the react router dom, and it operates normally when not using it.

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import './App.css';
// import Home from './routes/Home'
//import About from './routes/About'

function App(){
    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <Route />
        </HashRouter>
    )
}

export default App;
```

When importing HashRouter and Route, there is no error, but when using as follows, there is an error at the top.

please help me
I've been spending three hours here

Comment: Did you maybe accidentally include `useRef` as `import useRef from React` instead of `import { useRef } from React` ?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't understand the answer well because I'm a beginner at React.
But what is certain is that I didn't import or use the 'useRef' you said in the code I made myself.

Comment: Can you clarify what ***installed*** version of `react-router-dom` you are using? Can you also verify the `history` version? You can check both by running `npm list react-router-dom history` in the terminal in the project's root directory.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use Routes, rather than HashRouter

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import './App.css';
// import Home from './routes/Home'
//import About from './routes/About'

function App(){
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route />
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: HashRoutes is for very niche cases. Don't use it, unless its an old codebase.

Comment: Sorry. What I'm trying to use is a hash router. And even if I use routes, 'Object is not a function error' occurs the same.

Answer (score -1):

I'm asking you why you using hashRouter , are you sure about using it , though it's not recommended , check: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/hash-router

You can use browser router replacing hashrouter

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    {/* The rest of your app goes here */}
  </BrowserRouter>,
  root
);
```